# Android: How do I make a gird of images views and have the image change when I drag another image over it?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a grid of image views, that when i drag another view over them(this view essentially acts as a mouse pointer), it changes the image I drag over in the grid to a different image. When I drag the  "mouse" view away it will go back to normal.

Right now I have my mouse cursor view moving and have a grid of image views implemented with a grid view using a custom adaptor ( pictured below)

[image: image grid]

I can drag my cursor around but when ever I try to drag inside the gridview, it calls the image on the gridview's ontouch listener(only when i click on the image view, not when I slide over it). I also cannot seem to get onHover working on the images in the image View.

Also, if the mouse view is covering one of the grid images, the `ontouchlistener` of the image view the grid is not called.

What is the best way( types of views, etc) to use to go about implementing this?

Here is some relevant code from what I have so far.

This is where I set up my grid view in my activity

```
GridView gridView;
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);



    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,new String [25]));
    gridView.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {


        }
    });
    gridView.setClickable(false);
```

This is the `getView` function in my **adapter**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vibe_pad_section, null);


        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);


            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vibepadcircle);
            imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent e) {
                Log.e("here","here");
                switch (e.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.e("here2","here2");

                }
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar_high);
                return true;
            }
        });

         VibePad.padTargets.add(imageView);

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

 class  MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        ClipData dragData;
        View p = (View) v.getParent();
        Object index = p.getTag();
        final int which = Integer.parseInt(index.toString());
        boolean handled = true;
          Log.e(" in on drag","in on drag") ;

        switch (action) {


            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                // Report the drop/no-drop result to the user
                ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.bar_high);
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                // just drop it
                ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.vibepadcircle);
                break;

            default :
                break;
        }
        return handled;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class that extends OnDragListener:
When ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED occurs, you can change the underlying image to something else. When you exist (you've dragged the view outside the bounding box of the the image on your gridview) then you can change it back to it's original image

```
class  MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        ClipData dragData;
        View p = (View) v.getParent();
        Object index = p.getTag();
        final int which = Integer.parseInt(index.toString());
        boolean handled = true;


        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: 
                dragSku = event.getClipDescription().getLabel().toString();                 
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: 

                // Report the drop/no-drop result to the user
                final boolean dropped = event.getResult();
                compareInMotion = false;
                BaseAdapter lva = (BaseAdapter) gridview.getAdapter();
                lva.notifyDataSetChanged();
               break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // just drop it
                    ((ImageView) v).setImageBitmap(emptyImg);
                    setUpCompareItem((ImageView) v, dragSku);   break;

            default :
                break;                
        }
        return handled;
```

Comment: So I implemented my listener and set my GridView OnDrag listener to it. I am not picking up any drag events. Am I supposed assign this listener to each element in my custom adapter? I updated the code above